# MissingMethodException : UnityEngine.GameObject.setActive

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development, unityscript

I have added the below script to the NPC. on clicking on to the NPC the MessageBox (Panel in Canvas) should appear. But the MessageBox.setActive() part is not working. Below is the code.

```
import UnityEngine.UI;

var TextBoxOnCheck : int = 0;
var MessageBox : GameObject;
var TextBox : GameObject;
var TextMessage : String;
var QuestBox : GameObject;
var QuestText : GameObject;
var QuestName : String;

function OnMouseDown(){
    if (TextBoxOnCheck == 0) {
        TextBoxOnCheck = 1;
        MessageBox.setActive(true);
        TextBox.GetComponent.<Text>().text = TextMessage;
        QuestName = "Active Quest: 'Recover the loot'";
        QuestText.GetComponent.<Text>().text = QuestName;
    } else {
        TextBoxOnCheck = 0;
        MessageBox.setActive(false);
        TextMessage = "Villager: Get going then.";
    }
}
```

Error:
[image]

Rest of the code like changing QuestText to QuestName when clicking on NPC is working fine.

Comment: That looks like a simple **typo**: `setActive` != [`SetActive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) ... what Unity version are you using? `unityscript` was [deprecated years ago](https://blog.unity.com/community/unityscripts-long-ride-off-into-the-sunset) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo, s should be capitalized, turn it into `.SetActive()` instead of `.setActive()`

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)